# Deleting file on GridFS with GrifFsTemplate.delete

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to delete a file on GridFs but even if I don't get any error nothing happens.

```
Query query = new Query (Criteria.where("filename").is(filename));

this.gridFsTemplate.delete(query);
```

Any idea on how to do it? Is there maybe a better and more safe way to delete file maybe using ids?

Thanks.
Alexio

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your query doesn't retrieve anything. GridFS works not with one collection but with two, and therefore we may not be able to use `where()` methods from the `Criteria` class like we usually do.

I dug into Spring documentation and found that it conveniently offers a `GridFsCriteria` class providing static methods especially for making queries like yours. Subsequently, the correct answer to your issue should be :

```
Query query = new Query(GridFsCriteria.whereFileName().is(filename));
this.gridFsTemplate.delete(query);
```

I hope this helps ! You can find the documentation on Spring GridFS support [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#gridfs).

Comment: But how is different your way from mine? I instantiate the query object passing the Criteria in the constructor (that is a possibility) and you add the criteria to the query object in a second step.

Comment: You are **absolutely** right. To amend for that useless answer, here is a correct query using the `GridFsCriteria` helper class !